# Regular expression involving ">"

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a file, file.fas, containing DNA like:

```
>1 CHROMOSOME "rest of header"
ATTCTGAGATCTGAGATCTGAGATCTGAGA

>1 CHROMOSOME "rest of header"
TCTGAGATCTATTCTGAGATCTATTCTGAGATCT
```

Ideally, I would like replace the "1" with "Chr 1", so that it would look like:

```
>Chr1 CHROMOSOME "rest of header"
ATTCTGAGATCTGAGATCTGAGATCTGAGA

>Chr1 CHROMOSOME "rest of header"
TCTGAGATCTATTCTGAGATCTATTCTGAGATCT
```

I first tried it with sed, find op grep, e.g.

```
grep '>1' -f file.fas
```

Yet, it does not work. Does anyone has an idea why not?

Comment: add the `sed` code you tried... `grep` is only for searching not replacing

Comment: sed 's@>1@>Chr1@g' file.fas would work

Comment: What does not work? `">"` is not special in regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command

```
sed 's@>1@>Chr1@g' file.fas 


s - means substituion

@ - seperator

>1 - pattern to search for and replace

@ - seperator

>Chr1- pattern to substitue 

@ - sperator

g - substitute all occurences
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped! I'm going to 'accept' the answer when the time block has been lifted. :)

Comment: Good to know that it helped. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. can you please upvote the answer

Comment: `g` means "substitute all occurrences **on the current line**". You only have one `>1` on the line so having the `g` is misleading at best and would be a bug if `>1` DID appear elsewhere on the line, e.g. inside the `"rest of header"` string at the end of each `>1` line. Lose the `g`.

Comment: Assuming the file format has no other such occurences as >1 as it seems to be a DNA  file.